# Read Integer data from ms access using MFC C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc

I have a MS Access database that contains a table called ANIMATEUR and has 3 columns:

1. id(integer)
2. nom(varchar(12))
3. prenom(varchar(12))

I can read data of varchar columns but my problem is that when I try to read the integer column - I get an error... I think the problem is caused by casting from integer to CString.

Here is my code:

```
void gestionAnimateur::refreshList(){
    m_liste.DeleteAllItems();
    COleVariant var;
    CString nom,prenom,id;
    database.Open(cheminDB);
    record.Open(AFX_DAO_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE,"SELECT * FROM ANIMATEUR",NULL);

    int i = 0;
    while(! record.IsEOF()){
        record.GetFieldValue("id",var);
        id= (LPCSTR) var.pbstrVal;
        m_liste.InsertItem(i,id,0);

        record.GetFieldValue("prenom",var);
        prenom = (LPCSTR) var.pbstrVal;
        m_liste.SetItemText(i,1,prenom);

        record.GetFieldValue("nom",var);
        nom = (LPCSTR) var.pbstrVal;
        m_liste.SetItemText(i,2,nom);
        i++;
        record.MoveNext();
    }
    database.Close();
    record.Close();
}
```

solution here is the code ETDITED:

```
void gestionAnimateur::refreshList(){
m_liste.DeleteAllItems();
COleVariant var;
CString nom,prenom,idStr;
int idInt;
char idChar[12];
database.Open(cheminDB);
record.Open(AFX_DAO_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE,"SELECT * FROM ANIMATEUR",NULL);

int i = 0;
while(! record.IsEOF()){
    record.GetFieldValue("id",var);
    idInt =  var.intVal;
    itoa(idInt,idChar,10);
    idStr=idChar;
    m_liste.InsertItem(i,idStr,0);

    record.GetFieldValue("prenom",var);
    prenom = (LPCSTR) var.pbstrVal;
    m_liste.SetItemText(i,1,prenom);

    record.GetFieldValue("nom",var);
    nom = (LPCSTR) var.pbstrVal;
    m_liste.SetItemText(i,2,nom);
    i++;
    record.MoveNext();
}
database.Close();
record.Close();
```

}

Comment: Accept the answer (or write your own and accept this one as soon you could) to mark a question as _Solved_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to store an int into an CString.
First get your correct type with var.vt, and then get the correct value accordingly (if this is really an int then vt.intVal).
When you have your int, then you can transform it into a string ([std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) if you have C++11, or [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)).

By the way C cast are ugly and not safe, prefer [C++ casts](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

[More infos on Variant here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908601.aspx)

Comment: @SaidMarar Please consider marking the answer as accepted to help people with similar problem quickly locate the answer.